# How to send data from arduino to processing over wifi?

Tags: android, arduino, wifi

i'm actually trying to make a connected doorbell. Like when you press the button, the wifi-arduino ( ESP32 DEVKITV1 ) sends to my laptop (on Processing) the signal to make a song over wifi. The laptop is connected to a wireless to make the song stronger.

I don't suceed in the wifi connexion :

```
#include <WiFi.h>        // Include the Wi-Fi library
const char* ssid     = "Wifi Guest";         // The SSID (name) of the Wi-Fi network you want to connect to
const char* password = "";     // The password of the Wi-Fi network
const int  bouton = 14;
const int ledtemoin = 12;
int compteur = 0;
int etatbouton = 0;
int etatboutonprecedent = 0;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);         // Start the Serial communication to send messages to the computer
 delay(10);
 Serial.println('\n');
 pinMode(bouton, INPUT);
 pinMode(ledtemoin, OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(115200);
 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);             // Connect to the network
 Serial.print("Connecting to ");
 Serial.print(ssid);
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
   delay(500);
   Serial.print('.');
 }
 Serial.println('\n');
 Serial.println("Connection established!");
 Serial.print("IP address:\t");
 Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());         // Send the IP address of the ESP8266 to the computer
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
etatbouton = digitalRead(bouton);
if (etatbouton != etatboutonprecedent) {
  if (etatbouton == HIGH) {
    compteur++;
    digitalWrite (ledtemoin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("APPUI");
    Serial.print("nombre d'appuis:  ");
    Serial.println(compteur, DEC);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("PAS D'APPUI");
    digitalWrite (ledtemoin, LOW);
  }
  etatboutonprecedent = etatbouton;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the ESP32 (it is not an Arduino) to your WiFi router.

On

```
const char* ssid     = "Wifi Guest";         // The SSID (name) of the Wi-Fi network you want to connect to
const char* password = "";     // The password of the Wi-Fi network
```

You have to give the SSID and password of your router. This is the only way to connect your ESP32 to your network.

Using some library line WiFiManager, you can set your ESP32 as AccessPoint and so, if it can't connect to your router, it will create a new Network. So you can set the SSID and password over your phone or your PC, without coding it in your code.

But to keep it short: put your router ssid and router password in your code, if you want see your esp32 inside your network.